# Adding a newline character to al register while doing movsb ( Or how can I compare newline character with characters in an input string)

Tags: assembly, newline

I am trying to scan an input from user and the string is to be converted to something devoid of newline character so as to provide the name to a file. While scanning an input from the user somehow what happens is a newline gets appended to the string scanned. (Actually I am doing operations on two files here so I have used two strings.) . Here I am trying to  use movsb until the the newline character occurs by moving 10 in al . 10 which is newline in ascii but that doesn't work.

```
 section .data
        msg3 db "%s",10,0
        msg4 db "%s",0
        msg5 db "%d",10,0
        msg6 db 10

section .bss
    x resd 50
    y resd 50
    a resd 1
    d resd 1
    b resd 50
    c resd 50
section .text
    global main
    extern printf , scanf,gets
main :  
    xor eax,eax
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,x
    mov edx,30
    int 80h
    mov dword[a],eax
    push dword[a]
    push msg5
    call printf
    add esp,8

    xor eax,eax
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,y
    mov edx,30
    int 80h
    mov dword[d],eax


    xor eax,eax
    mov esi,x
    mov edi,b
    mov ecx,dword[a]
    mov al,10
    cld
repne   movsb   
    mov esi,y
    mov edi,c
    mov ecx,dword[d]
repne   movsb
    xor eax,eax
```

Comment: `mov byte [ecx + eax - 1], 0`, right after the sys_read, will zero-terminate the input string (overwrites the linefeed). If you wish to use "string instructions", look into `scasb`.

Comment: Oh yeah...` extern printf , scanf,gets`. Please don't use gets!

Comment: I know gets is not at all useful , I was just trying my luck with everything. Yesterday one of my friends also told me to mov a zero to terminate it i.e overwriting linefeed. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did something like this it worked. Also some part of the earlier code was flawed .Thank you Frank Kotler.

```
    xor eax,eax
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,x
    mov edx,30
    int 80h
    mov dword[a],eax
    push dword[a]
    push msg5
    call printf
    add esp,8

    xor eax,eax
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,y
    mov edx,30
    int 80h
    mov dword[d],eax


    xor eax,eax
    mov esi,x
    mov edi,b
    mov ecx,dword[d]
    mov al,0
    cld
repne   movsb   
    mov ecx,dword[d]
    mov byte[ecx+b-1],0
    mov esi,y
    mov edi,c
    mov ecx,dword[d]
repne   movsb
    xor eax,eax
    mov ecx,dword[d]
    mov byte[ecx+c-1],0

    xor eax,eax
    mov esi,b
    mov edi,x
    mov ecx,dword[d]
    mov al,0
    cld
repne   movsb   
    mov al,0
    mov ecx,dword[d]

    mov esi,c
    mov edi,y
    mov ecx,dword[d]
repne   movsb
    xor eax,eax
```